# How to test if two btrfs snapshots are identical or not?

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

As far as I know, in order to determine if a snapshot is identical with another one or not, we should check if `Received UUID` of destination is equal to UUID of source snapshot or not.

But this time, this procedure can not be applied:

```
root@aea3:/mnt/zencefil/snapshots/rootfs# btrfs send rootfs.20170705T1334/ | pv | btrfs receive /mnt/aea3/manual-snapshots/                                              
At subvol rootfs.20170705T1334/                                                                                                                                          
At subvol rootfs.20170705T1334                                                                                                                                          
37.8GiB 0:37:27 [17.2MiB/s] [                                                                            
root@aea3:/mnt/zencefil/snapshots/rootfs# btrfs sub show rootfs.20170705T1334/
/mnt/zencefil/snapshots/rootfs/rootfs.20170705T1334
        Name:                   rootfs.20170705T1334
        UUID:                   e66ace1b-3efc-5d40-b3ca-af000110e89d
        Parent UUID:            85bc19f1-9d61-da43-a4be-40c717aee652
        Received UUID:          c6f65496-f21d-c049-b2e2-44007b269dc6
        Creation time:          2017-07-10 12:47:16 +0300
        Subvolume ID:           2561
        Generation:             4331
        Gen at creation:        4327
        Parent ID:              257
        Top level ID:           257
        Flags:                  readonly
        Snapshot(s):
                                snapshots/rootfs/rootfs.20170710T1242
root@aea3:/mnt/zencefil/snapshots/rootfs# btrfs sub show /mnt/aea3/manual-snapshots/rootfs.20170705T1334/
/mnt/aea3/manual-snapshots/rootfs.20170705T1334
        Name:                   rootfs.20170705T1334
        UUID:                   53bc9463-2fe6-9a41-b17d-a0a8dc5e6086
        Parent UUID:            -
        Received UUID:          c6f65496-f21d-c049-b2e2-44007b269dc6
        Creation time:          2017-07-12 10:36:50 +0300
        Subvolume ID:           1832
        Generation:             64698
        Gen at creation:        64627
        Parent ID:              1831
        Top level ID:           1831
        Flags:                  readonly
        Snapshot(s):
root@aea3:/mnt/zencefil/snapshots/rootfs# btrfs --version
btrfs-progs v4.11
```

However, when I create and send a test snapshot and send it on the same drives on the same machine, it works as expected:

```
root@aea3:/mnt/zencefil/test# btrfs send mytest1/ | pv | btrfs receive /mnt/aea3/test/
At subvol mytest1/
At subvol mytest1
 540 B 0:00:00 [73.1KiB/s] [                                                                                                                                        ]
root@aea3:/mnt/zencefil/test# btrfs sub show mytest1/
/mnt/zencefil/test/mytest1
        Name:                   mytest1
        UUID:                   3a932406-8a81-5047-9a23-9333564752c2
        Parent UUID:            -
        Received UUID:          -
        Creation time:          2017-07-12 11:41:22 +0300
        Subvolume ID:           2567
        Generation:             4369
        Gen at creation:        4367
        Parent ID:              5
        Top level ID:           5
        Flags:                  readonly
        Snapshot(s):
root@aea3:/mnt/zencefil/test# btrfs sub show /mnt/aea3/test/mytest1/
/mnt/aea3/test/mytest1
        Name:                   mytest1
        UUID:                   98d59473-5a47-7742-bcf7-47262b9cada2
        Parent UUID:            -
        Received UUID:          3a932406-8a81-5047-9a23-9333564752c2
        Creation time:          2017-07-12 11:44:16 +0300
        Subvolume ID:           1844
        Generation:             64738
        Gen at creation:        64737
        Parent ID:              5
        Top level ID:           5
        Flags:                  readonly
        Snapshot(s):
```

What is the missing point here?

Answer (score -1):

In the first case the snapshot `/mnt/zencefil/snapshots/rootfs/rootfs.20170705T1334` has been received from an other location before. The original UUID is stored as `Received UUID`. When transmitting this snapshot again this `Received UUID` is also used for the copy.

Therefore in order to determine if a snapshot is identical with (that is copy of) another, check if Received UUID of destination is equal to **Received UUID of source, if present, or** UUID of source, otherwise.